# Смещение по номеру в массиве

Tags: php

Никак не могу разобраться, есть такой код:

```
$a1 = ['k1' => '1', 'k2' => '2','k3' => '3', 'k4' => '4', 'k5' => '5'];
$a2 = ['k1' => '-1', 'k2' => '-2','k3' => '-3', 'k4' => '-4', 'k5' => '-5'];

$ix = 1; // номер на который нужно переместить
$k = 'k3'; // ключ, который хотим переместить
$i = 1; // номер итерации
$oldk1 = $oldk2 = '';
foreach($a as $key => $value) {
    if($k === $key && $ix != $i) {
        $oldk1 = $value;
        $oldk2 = $a2[$k];
        unset($a1[$k], $a2[$k]);
    }
    if($i === $ix) {
        $a1[$k] = $oldk1;
        $a2[$k] = $oldk2;
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

Но он не работает, почему не могу понять, что я не пытался делать у меня не получается решить эту задачу.

Заключается она в следующем:

2 массива с одинаковыми ключами, но с разными значениями, они должны всегда в одинаковом порядке идти по ключам.

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я захочу к примеру, чтобы `k3` стояло на `1` месте или на другом любом, я ввожу номер от 1 и до максимума в массиве и чтобы у меня в 2 массивах переставлялось на указанный номер и чтобы уже было так:

```
$a1 = ['k3' => '3', 'k1' => '1', 'k2' => '2', 'k4' => '4', 'k5' => '5'];
$a2 = ['k3' => '-3', 'k1' => '-1', 'k2' => '-2', 'k4' => '-4', 'k5' => '-5'];
```

**UPD 1:**

Неужели никто не знает, как это сделать?
Я уже даже пытался делать с еще одним массивом и просто потом добавлять в нужной итерации, но он все равно в конец летит...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

```
$a1 = ['k1' => '1', 'k2' => '2','k3' => '3', 'k4' => '4', 'k5' => '5'];
$a2 = ['k1' => '-1', 'k2' => '-2','k3' => '-3', 'k4' => '-4', 'k5' => '-5'];
$k = 'k3';
$i = 1;
$element = array_splice($a1, array_flip(array_keys($a1))[$k], 1);
$a1 = array_merge(
    array_slice($a1, 0, $i - 1), 
    $element,
    array_slice($a1, $i - 1)
);
$a2 = array_merge($a1, $a2);

print_r($a1);
print_r($a2);
```